# Rails 4, Draper: authenticated user and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, draper

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <!-- lots of html/erb -->
<% end %>
```

This view pattern seems to not separate concerns.

I wrap several views in my app with logic demanding the user is signed in and would instead like to separate concerns and put the <% if user_signed_in? %> logic where it belongs...this seems like a decorator thing to me (hence the Draper tag).

What is best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure understood your question, but try to answer. 
At first to separate logic you dont need to use decorators in front of all, they serves for a little another thing. 
To separate logic you can use simple partials depending on current user state, for ex:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'file_with_html_for_signed_user' %>
<% else %>
    <%= render 'file_with_html_for_non_signed_user' %>
<% end %>
```

You can declare this statement in your `layouts/application.html.erb`